# Deserialize WCF web service request in PHP

Tags: php, wcf, soap, service, web

I have a WCF web service with a Login operation taking a company name, user name and password as the three parameters. I am trying to create a PHP client app to communicate with this service. No matter what I pass to the Login operation I get the following error:

```
OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find node type 'Element' with name 'Login' and namespace ''. Found node type 'Element' with name 'parameters' and namespace ''
```

My client app:

```
<?php
        try
        {
            $client = new SoapClient("https://somewhere.com/DataServiceRxPublic.svc?wsdl");

            //$params = array(
            //        'parameters' => array(
            //                'Param' => array(
            //                        array('Name' => 'loginCompany', 'Value' => 'XXX'),
            //                        array('Name' => 'loginId', 'Value' => 'XXX'),
            //                        array('Name' => 'loginPwd', 'Value' => 'XXX')
            //)));

            //$params = array(
            //        'Login' => array(
            //                array('Name' => 'loginCompany', 'Value' => 'XXX'),
            //                array('Name' => 'loginId', 'Value' => 'XXX'),
            //                array('Name' => 'loginPwd', 'Value' => 'XXX')
            //));

            //$params = array(
            //        'Login' => array(
            //                'parameters' => array(
            //                       array('Name' => 'loginCompany', 'Value' => 'XXX'),
            //                        array('Name' => 'loginId', 'Value' => 'XXX'),
            //                        array('Name' => 'loginPwd', 'Value' => 'XXX')
            //)));

            //$params = array(
            //        array('Name' => 'loginCompany', 'Value' => 'XXX'),
            //        array('Name' => 'loginId', 'Value' => 'XXX'),
            //        array('Name' => 'loginPwd', 'Value' => 'XXX')
            //);

            $params = array(
                    'loginCompany' => 'XXX',
                    'loginId' => 'XXX',
                    'loginPwd' => 'XXX'
            );

            $obj->loginCompany = 'XXX';
            $obj->loginId = 'XXX';
            $obj->loginPwd = 'XXX';

            //$result = $client->Login($obj);
            //$result = $client->Login($params);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
                print_r($e);
        }
    }
?>
```

$params being the different array permutations I've based off several different examples online.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You do realise `$params` is being overwritten each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to extend the SOAPClient and override the __doRequest() method to replace the mismatched soap headers.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that there should have been something named "Login", but was named "parameters".

Go get [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) and with your WSDL follow the steps I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893304/wsdl-service-response-once-variables-are-sent-php) to debug what you are actually sending. If you cannot compare what the service expects vs. what you are sending, this will be way too much trial-and-error.

If you need more external help, we'd need the WSDL resource - without it, nobody knows which request structure is expected.

Comment: Got soapUI, ran a test Login and it was successful. Also, updated question with link to WSDL.

Comment: Does that mean your question is solved, or that you still have a problem? What did you do with SoapUI, e.g. mocked something?

Comment: I still have a problem. I believe it may have something to do with the wsdl. Both my c# client and soapUI can communicate with the web service. The PHP SoapClient still throws an exception while deserializing the request.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this error by modifying service namespace on server side.

`[ServiceContract(Name="Service", Namespace = "https://sample.eu")]`

Namespace was empty before.